# Adding a custom navigation controller transition breaks the interactive pop/back gesture slide, can I re-enable it easily?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I set my `navigationController`'s delegate to a custom object that implements `UINavigationController`, then I implemented `navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?` to return a custom animation controller for a custom push animation, and `nil` if it's a pop animation (so it applies the normal "pop" animation). However this disabled the slide gesture to go back/pop the view controller.

Is there an easy way to add it back?

Comment: Are you sure that is the only change you made? Are you still showing the navigationBar?

Comment: Yeah, I set it as the delegate on my navigation controller, and that's it. And the navigation bar is still visible.